# Cannot Do Anything With apt-get - broken dependencies with kmod. What do?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

```
(precise)fatih@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kmod : Breaks: module-init-tools (< 4)
        Breaks: module-init-tools:i386 (< 4)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I've been unable to do anything. install wont work, configure doesn't help, and neither does updating stuff. What can I do to fix this dependency?

```
(precise)fatih@localhost:~$ lsb_release -a; apt-cache policy kmod module-init-tools module-init-tools:i386
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
kmod:
  Installed: 15-0ubuntu6
  Candidate: 15-0ubuntu6
  Version table:
 *** 15-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
module-init-tools:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 15-0ubuntu6
  Version table:
     15-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
module-init-tools:i386:
  Installed: 3.16-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.16-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.16-1ubuntu2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Edit 2:

```
kmod:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 15-0ubuntu6
  Version table:
     15-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: As in, input that in the terminal? @user.dz

Comment: Try `apt-get purge -s module-init-tools:i386` . See if it is going to remove only one pacakge.

Comment: Nothing happened, but something new came up:
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 alsa-base : Depends: module-init-tools (>= 3.2.1)
 initramfs-tools : Depends: module-init-tools
 linux-sound-base : Depends: module-init-tools (>= 3.2.1)
 powermgmt-base : Depends: module-init-tools`

Comment: Is this after you removeed `module-init-tools:i386` ? if so then install its amd64 package instead  `sudo apt-get install module-init-tools`

Comment: I'm not sure if it was even removed. I get a weird error when trying to install :  `module-init-tools : Conflicts: module-init-tools:i386`
 ; `module-init-tools:i386 : Conflicts: module-init-tools` @user.dz

Comment: Could you post output of `apt-get purge -s module-init-tools:i386`

Comment: @user.dz Same exact output as the one I posted two comments ago (four missing dependencies). [I'd move this to chat but I don't have enough rep :L]

Comment: You could post it to http://paste.ubuntu.com and put link in comment as you put many links in the question yet

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23490773/

Comment: hmm it doesn't let remove it using apt, Could you post output of this `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --dry-run module-init-tools:i386`

Comment: @user.dz http://paste.ubuntu.com/23491159/ Hrm. It's pretty persistent.

Comment: How is about `sudo dpkg --remove --force-depends --dry-run module-init-tools:i386`

Comment: @user.dz Something new! http://paste.ubuntu.com/23491294/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `module-init-tools:i386` installed where `module-init-tools` (amd64) should be installed instead. Probably you got from a previous PPA, because I can't find this version `3.16-1ubuntu2` in the official repository.

Another point `module-init-tools` is a transient package for `kmod`, they should have same version installed, otherwise you get a conflict.

1. Force to remove module-init-tools:i386 even it has some depandants

   ```
   sudo dpkg --remove --force-depends module-init-tools:i386
   ```
2. Install its amd64 component instead

   ```
   sudo apt-get install module-init-tools
   ```
3. Run APT fix to check if any thing missing

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

Comment: Bloody heck, this fixes it! Thank you so much for the help! Don't know how I screwed this up in the first place.